# Harmonic Function (Square Wave Fourier Series) in Python using Nested Loops and Lists

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, sum, nested-loops

Apologies for the lack of in-line pictures, I am a first time poster.

I am trying to plot a square wave via a Fourier Series using nested loops with matplotlib.

The square wave is given by the function:

[image: Square wave function]

- I take an input `n_loop` to dictate N and the granularity of `x` over a range `-pi` to `pi`.
- I take a string input and create a `.dat` of values that are then used to plot the harmonic function.
- I use a nested loop to deal with looping through `x` and looping through `i`.

However, whilst all functions of the program work, the graph I get is incorrect.

Is there something wrong in the way I am appending `f`?

Any help would be appreciated, code below with my current output:

```python
# Import relevant python modules
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

# Main method
def main():
    
    # number of data points and error handling input
    while True:
        try:
            n_loop = int(input("enter an positive integer N (granularity and sum): "))
        except ValueError:
            print("N has to be a positive integer")
            continue
        if n_loop <= 0:
            print("N has to be a positive integer")
        else:
            break

    #file name for .dat
    while True:
        try:
            output_name = str(input("Enter the name of the output file: "))
        except ValueError: #don't even know if you can trigger this but
            print("please use a string")
            continue
        else:
            break
                
    # open output file
    out_file = open(output_name+".dat","w")
    
    # prepare data lists
    fi_values = []
    x_values = []
    y_values = []
    x = -math.pi
    f = 0
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(f)

    # obtain function values and write them to file
    for k in range(n_loop):
        x = 2*k*math.pi/n_loop-math.pi    #this is the range -pi to pi: for i=0 x =-pi, for i=n_loop x =pi
        for i in range(n_loop):
            fi_values += [(1/((2*i)-1))*math.sin(((2*i)-1)*x)]    #harmonic function
        f = sum(fi_values)
        

        # append data to lists and output file
        x_values.append(x)
        y_values.append(f)
    
        out_file.write(str(x) + " " + str(f) + "\n")

    # close output file
    out_file.close()

    # plot result
    pyplot.plot(x_values,y_values)
    pyplot.suptitle('Plotting the Harmonic function')
    pyplot.xlabel('X')
    pyplot.ylabel('Y')
    pyplot.show()

# Execute main method
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Output of `N=n_loops=200`:

[image: My result]

What it should look like for `N=200` (x continuous):

[image: Actual result]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to dump the function values to an intermediate file?

Comment: @butterflyknife hi thanks for looking at this, yes I need to keep the .dat(s)

Comment: No worries. Have a look at my answer and please upvote if it was useful!

Comment: @butterflyknife This is a fantastic analysis, and explanation. Thank you very, very much. The list clear and sum limits makes complete sense, I'd convinced myself wrong on both accounts. Will go away and learn about list comprehension.:)

The dependency on n_loop of x intervals and the series iteration I think is an interesting one! Weird scale-y stuff.
Thank you again kind stranger. ((ps. can't up-doot publicly as new user but have put as accepted answer))

Comment: You can return the favour by upvoting and accepting :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

def f(x, N):
    # Learn about list comprehensions so you don't have to loop through lists!
    return sum([1/(2*i - 1) * math.sin((2 * i - 1) * x) for i in range(1, N + 1)]) 

N = 200
x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.05)
y = np.array([f(x_i, N) for x_i in x]) # List comprehension again.
pyplot.plot(x,y)

# Dumping the file to text is separate to plotting.
out_file = open("blah.dat","w")
out_file.write(str(x) + " " + str(y) + "\n")
out_file.close()
```

In terms of what's wrong with your code, I can see some things that are obviously wrong, but I haven't followed them through to why they're giving you the output that you're getting.

```
for k in range(n_loop): # See [1]
    x = 2*k*math.pi/n_loop-math.pi   
    for i in range(n_loop): # See note [3]
        fi_values += [(1/((2*i)-1))*math.sin(((2*i)-1)*x)]    # [2]
    f = sum(fi_values)
```

[1]: Style note: you should be looping over x values in a grid from -pi to pi: this is independent of N. (Unless you explicitly want the size of your grid to depend on N, but there's no good reason to here).

[2]: The main error. You're not clearing the list `fi_values` when you finish each loop, so it's acting as a running total.

[3]: Another big error. You are summing terms `0` to `N - 1`, not `1` to `N`.

**Final Edit*.* Your fixed code:

```
# obtain function values and write them to file
for k in range(n_loop):
    fi_values = []                         # clear before starting a new loop.
    x = 2 * k * math.pi / n_loop - math.pi # I'll keep what you wrote here.
    for i in range(1, n_loop + 1):         # make sure limits of sum are not off by one.
        fi_values += [(1/((2*i)-1))*math.sin(((2*i)-1)*x)] 
    f = sum(fi_values)

    # append data to lists and output file
    x_values.append(x)
    y_values.append(f)
```